# Stop or Cancel the Old Navigation screen When I go next navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanted to copy my code but it's too long. However, actually I have two navigation pages one of them is `HomePage` and the other one is `ResultPage`. First I execute the operation in `HomePage` and then it passes to the `ResultPage`. But when I click on Android's back button, it navigates back to `HomePage`. I don't want to go back. I want to cancel `HomePage` operations. How can I do this?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo';
import CountdownCircle from 'react-native-countdown-circle';



class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    
}
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = ({
      count: 0,
      count2: 1 ,
      randCount: Math.ceil((Math.random()*10 + 1)),
      süre:false
  
    })
 

  
}
```

```js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,BackHandler} from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import CountdownCircle from 'react-native-countdown-circle';


class ResultScreen extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    
    }
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
  
      this.state = ({
        count: 20,
        count2: 1 ,
        count3: 1 ,
        randCount: Math.ceil((Math.random()*10 + 1)),
        durum1: false,
        durum2: false
    
      })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `BackHandler` listener in your ResultPage and instead of going back to Homepage, you can pass your own function to run when user presses the back button. It cannot cancel the operations in Homepage, but it won't go back like you need, so Homepage functions don't run again.

Comment: please share this code, because ı tried but it didnt work

Comment: BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', yourBackButtonFunction). This is how you can add a listener. Add it inside componentDidMount, and when navigating away from this screen, you should remove this listener too. Please refer to BackHandler section in react native documentation.